# Regular expression in C#.net

Tags: c#, regex

i needed a function for validate the entered date. whether entered date is in correct format.
i browsed the web and got a regular expression for it.
Its works fine except when you enter 12/12/YYYY(on any year) it shows error saying that its not a valid date.

```
bool IsDate(string date)  
        {
            Match dobMatch = Regex.Match(date, @"^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/(0[13578]|1[02])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\/(0[13456789]|1[012])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/02\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\/02\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$");
            if (!dobMatch.Success)
            {return true;}
            else
            {return false;}
        }
```

i

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Try `DateTime.TryParse()`.**

This parses dates for you. This method allows you to pass the `CultureInfo` if the culture you want to use to parse the date with.

**Alternatively, if you really want to use regular expressions, have a look at http://regexlib.com/.** That is a comprehensive library of regular expressions with ratings per regular expression.

Comment: Did the function mentioned validates the date whether exist or not in feburary also like 30/2/2011

Comment: Yes. It can only produce (the `out` parameter) a valid date, including leap years.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use [DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx) or [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx) far easier than using a Regex.

Comment: Did the function mentioned validates the date whether exist or not in feburary also like 30/2/2011

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
^([0]?[1-9]|[1|2][0-9]|[3][0|1])[./-]([0]?[1-9]|[1][0-2])[./-]([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})$
```

Or go to following link , http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=4&categoryId=5

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression only validates the character data in a string and does not say anything about the actual validity of the data in that string.

To check a string as a valid date in .Net use the following:

```
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParse(someString, out dt))
{
   //Parsed as a valid date whose value is now in the variable dt
}
else 
{
   //Not a valid date
}
```

Comment: Did the function mentioned validates the date whether exist or not in feburary also like 30/2/2011

Comment: Yes it does, if the date is not valid then `TryParse` will return false